# Syntax error with SQL associative entity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea why this code won't work. Throws syntax error, but from my knowledge this should work. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

```
insert into playerteam(playerId, teamId) select id from player where 
  player.firstname='John' and select id from team where team.`name`='Swim Team';
```

Comment: You should look into how to use sub queries with insert statement - your query format is totally wrong...

Comment: I understand where I went wrong, I wasn't nesting properly, and was running query through where clause. I'm still new to this, but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as given below:

```
INSERT INTO playerteam(playerId, teamId) 
SELECT (SELECT id FROM player WHERE player.firstname='John'), 
    (SELECT id FROM team WHERE team.`name`='Swim Team');
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for the feedback. I wasn't paying attention to the where clause. Still a noob here XD

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
player.firstname='John' and select id from team where team.`name`='Swim  Team';
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't just return an entire query result as a `where` clause. You have to somehow TEST that result, e.g.

```
... AND EXISTS select ...
         ^^^^
```

Comment: @Suraz 's solution actually worked for me, thanks for the feedback, I will look into the exists aswell!

Answer (score 1):

your `select` query is not correct- you can't combine two queries by using `select ... AND select ...`, you need to use `join`

For example (but you need to add here the ON part for the join, in order to connect the two tables):

```
insert into playerteam(playerId, teamId) select player.id as playerId, 
  team.id as teamId from player inner join team on {ADD HERE COLUMNS TO JOIN BY}
where player.firstname='John' and  team.`name`='Swim Team';
```

Comment: Yep, thank you, I got it working. I believe this solution is a bit more work then is needed for what I have to do, but thanks again for the feedback.